# Adjust horizontal (preferred) size of an XYPlot in JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I have an `XYPlot` with an `XYBarRenderer`. This is used for a histogram. The horizontal spacing between the bins is too large, the bars are too wide. How can I decrease the 'preferred' bar width in this setting?

Note that `setMaximumBarWidth` is not defined for `XYBarRenderer`.

Answer (score 1):

By default the [XYBarRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBarRenderer.html) will take its dimensions from the dataset which, in your case, will be determined by the actual bin widths.  For presentation, you can override that and trim the bar widths down a little (or a lot) by calling the [setMargin()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBarRenderer.html#setMargin%28double%29) method.

Comment: The margin is already minimum (zero), so that doesn't help. The only solution I found so far is to set the preferred size of the chart panel, which is kind of ugly.

Comment: The margin is ignored if it is less than or equal to zero.  Try setting it to 0.2 and see the effect.